# Laravel migration -> change column to tinyInteger results into double column

Tags: php, laravel-9

I'm new to Laravel, and I need to update my current DB with Laravel migration

I need to change a column type to tinyInt, so I'm using this command in script :

```php
Schema::whenTableHasColumn($tb_name, $column_name, function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->tinyInteger($column_name)->change();
});
```

But when I look at my table, the column type is double. Did I miss something ?

Comment: It seems the tinyInt can't be changed, as it is not mentioned. 

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#updating-column-attributes

Maybe have a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/45591717/5841606 - while it is about Laravel 5.4 it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ok, nvm, I'm just dumb...

It may help people who try to change column types that aren't "accepted" by Laravel Migrations.

To use those types, you need to do like in @Sethu answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67491126/16545512

Comment: Back to my problem, I just made a mistake while adding tinyInteger type

Instead of doing this :

```php
if (!Type::hasType("tinyinteger")) {
    Type::addType("tinyinteger", TinyIntegerType::class);
}
```

I did this :
```php
if (!Type::hasType("tinyinteger")) {
    Type::addType("tinyinteger", FloatType::class);
}
```

So that's why I got a double while trying to change into tinyInteger ^^'

Comment: And yes I'm adding it here because i can't answer my own post with so low reputation score :/
But thanks @Uwe ^^